# Where results displayed are less than current time

Tags: oracle, timestamp, oracle-sqldeveloper, where-clause

On Oracle SQL Developer, I'm looking to write a where function that gives me the last 7 days of data. I can write that part myself fine, but the extra part that I need to add on to the end is that I only want results that are for the past 7 days before my current time.

For example, if I query at 14:00 today, I would want it to return results for the past 7 days with data only up until 14:00, as opposed to the full day.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

SYSDATE is the Oracle built in date function that supplies the current date / time accurate to 1 second. All you have to do is:

```
select * 
  from whatever
 where whatever.datecol between sysdate - 7 and  sysdate;
```